# kth smallest element - what's wrong with this code?

Tags: c

I dry ran the code many times but can't find the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {9,8,5,10,2};
    int i, j, k, small;
    scanf("%d", &k);
    int n=5;
    int asc[k];
    if(k<n)
    {
        for(i=0; i<k; i++)
        {
            small=arr[i];
            for(j=i; j<n; j++)
            {
                if(arr[j]<small)
                {
                    small=arr[j];
                }
            }
            asc[i]=small;
        }
        printf("%d", asc[k-1]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output should return kth smallest element. also I created an array "asc" to store the smallest elements in ascending order after each iteration of outer loop.

Output - 2 every time

Expected - when inserted any value(k) less than n, it should return kth smallest element.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195239/discussion-on-question-by-nishant001-kth-smallest-element-whats-wrong-with-th).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Guys I did it with simple sorting. I was trying to do it without using any sorting or any recursion but it seems very difficult if not impossible. Anyways thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

What would happen if the smallest element is the last one? That is your case: `{9,8,5,10,2}`
On each iteration you find the smallest element (`2`) and assign it to the current element of `asc`. The result is `asc[] = {2, 2, 2}` (consists of k equal elements).

Comment: Not just the last element. This will happen whenever the index of the smallest element is at least `k`.

Comment: @Barmar for sure the issue is wider, but I'm explaining to the author of this question what's going on in his example. Being generic would make the things worse ;)

Comment: Yeah now I realize that it will pick 2 as the smallest element every time. Will get back to you.